# Next.js issue with formik validation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

`Please look below to the image:`

[image]

`
A problem has been encountered when choosing a specific value
The options appear again successfully
But the first choice is still required and the value has been chosen but is still required.
I have tried a lot to solve a problem, and I only got this result. Please help me in this problem.
If you can look to code, I will be grateful.
`

```
export function IndustryRestaurantSelect() {
  const typee = [
    {
      name: "حدد من القائمة",
      value: "",
      states: [],
    },
    {
      name: "مطعم",
      value: "restaurant",
      states: [
        {
          id: "foodtruck",
          name: "فود ترك",
        },
        {
          id: "restaurant",
          name: "مطعم",
        },
        {
          id: "cafe",
          name: "مقهى",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "تجزئة",
      value: "retail",
      states: [
        {
          name: "بلا",
        },
        {
          name: "بلا",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("حدد من القائمة");
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const changeCountry = (event) => {
    setCountry(event.target.value);
    setStates(typee.find((ctr) => ctr.value === event.target.value).states);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="form__field anime-item">
        <label className="register__label">نوع النشاط</label>
        <Field name="businessType" component="select" value={country} onChange={changeCountry}>
          {/* <option value="restaurant">مطعم</option>
          <option value="cafe">مقهى</option>
          <option value="foodtruck">فود ترك</option> */}
          {typee.map((ctr) => (
            <option value={ctr.value}>{ctr.name}</option>
          ))}
        </Field>
        <div className="form__field__error">
          <ErrorMessage name="businessType">{(msg) => <span>{msg}</span>}</ErrorMessage>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form__field anime-item">
        <label className="register__label">نوع النشاط</label>
        <Field name="industry" component="select">
          <option value="">حدد من القائمة</option>
          {/* <option value="restaurant">مطعم</option>
          <option value="cafe">مقهى</option>
          <option value="foodtruck">فود ترك</option> */}
          {states.map((state) => (
            <option value={state.id}>{state.name}</option>
          ))}
        </Field>
        <div className="form__field__error">
          <ErrorMessage name="industry">{(msg) => <span>{msg}</span>}</ErrorMessage>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```